# Best way to delete LRO and RLO characters in Python

Tags: python, web, type-conversion, html-encode

Is there any elegant solution or best practice how to remove RLO and LRO characters?

Explanation of my problem: I get/parse `&#x202D;400 000&#x202C;` string from the website. I need this string convert into integer type (just 400000 number value).

Any ideas how to elegantly remove this characters? (`&#x202D;` and `&#x202D;`)

Thanks!

//Update:

`capacity_value = capacity_value.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode().replace(" ", "")`

(encode() and decode() functions works but I don't like it. Is there any better solution in this case?)

Comment: Python strings are Unicode, not ASCII. Unicode isn't some kind of escape sequence, it's how characters are stored as bytes. What you posted is neither RLO or LRO characters, it's an HTML escape sequence. Even though the characters they represent are way out of the US-ASCII range, the escape sequences themselves are US-ASCII so your code has no effect - except perhaps mangle the text

Comment: Use `html.unescape` to unescape the HTM- encoded characters and get the actual Unicode string. After that, you could just remove these characters with eg `.replace('\u202d','')` or `str = re.sub(r"(\u202c|\u202d)", "", str)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `str` type has a `translate` method which can be use to replace or remove characters. Here if you want to remove space, RLO and LRO, you could do:

```
transtable = str.maketrans('', '', ' \u202d\u202c')
capacity_value = capacity_value..translate(transtable)
```